# javascript slice within loop for array

Tags: javascript, for-loop, while-loop, slice

I want to take an array output like the following:

```
 [a,
  b,
  c,
  d,
  e,
  f]
```

and slice it into sections, then output each new array on a newline like this:

```
 [a,b
  c,d
  e,f]
```

Here's what i have so far:

```
var data = "";
for (i = 0; i < 4; i+=2) {
data += output.slice(i,2);

}
return data;
```

I've been working at this for some time now trying different things to make this work but no luck. I'm new to JS, so i need some help.

Comment: Hint: If you increment the start index you also need to increment the end index

Comment: Do you want to convert a 1-d array into an array of 2 element arrays or build a string with 2 array elements on each line?

Comment: no one noticed the typo on the question :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have six elements in your array, you need to iterate to 6 not 4. The best way to do that is to use the length of your array, so if the length changes you don't need to change the loop. When taking a slice you also want `slice(i, i+2)`

If you just want to make a string, you can add a `\n` character in each iteration:

```js
let output = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

var data = "";
for (i = 0; i < output.length; i+=2) { 
    data += output.slice(i,i+2).join(" ") + "\n";
}
console.log(data);
```

Comment: This pretty much did what i needed. I didn't realize i needed to increase the end index as well. I added a comma for join instead of an empty space. `.join(",")`

Answer (score 1):

```js
let data = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
    
var output = "";
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i+=2) { 
    output += data.slice(i, i+2).join(",") + "\n";
}
console.log(`[${output.substring(0, output.lastIndexOf("\n"))}]`);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming they are only chars (1 char) and there are not empty chars, you can `join`, match the chars as pairs using the regex `/(.+?){2}/g`, `map` to `char,char` and finally `join` with `\n`.

```js
let output = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'],
    data = output.
           join('').
           match(/(.+?){2}/g).
           map(s => s.split('').join(',')).join('\n');


console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

While zos0K's answer should suffice for slicing, one point I would like to mention is that if you just want to output the string and do nothing else with the resulting sliced arrays, I would recommend that you directly add them to a string and then print it out as aposed to creating a new array for every couple strings. While it does the job, Array.prototype.slice returns a new array each time, and creating new arrays can get expensive fairly quickly.